# Meanjs grunt build jquery $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, gruntjs, meanjs

I have developed a somewhat large meanjs application and when I run grunt build it gives me Jquery issue as following.

[image]

I used Jquery self invoking methods too as follows. But it also give me error.

```
(function ($){
    $('#renew').modal('hide');
})(jQuery);
```

[image]

Because of these issue 'public/dist/application.min.js' is not creating.

I can see jquery has loaded to the browser as follows.

[image]

Comment: Check if jQuery is includes before you do these statements. This sais that jQuery has not been included yet.

Comment: @Robbin'Roboroads'Schepers Please see my edited question, Jquery.js file loaded correctly.

Comment: Could still be the case, i can see you run javascript before the jquery include. What happens if you place the jquery include tag directly under the `<head>` tag?

Comment: @Robbin'Roboroads'Schepers this issue is not related to jquery loading order as I feel. Jquery functions are working on browser properly even in current implementation. But when I run grunt build command above errors are displaying and it breaks the minify js file creation of MEAN JS application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is an error. In fact I believe it is a warning that jshint is giving because you are using `'use strict';` and it doesn't know that `$` was defined (in jquery file).

You can just add `$` to the `globals` in your `.jshintrc` file like this:

```
{
    "globals" : {
        "$": false
    }
}
```

Or add the following line to all the js files that use `$`

```
/*global $:false */
```

As a side note, you should also be able to make it build even with the warnings by using `grunt --force` but still you should fix it as explained above.

Comment: It works for me.But even if all these warnings are fixed still public/dist/application.min.js do not build. I used grunt --force build. But my console still displaying backend Nodejs warnings.

Comment: That's odd. You have to carefully check your gruntfile looking for file paths that you might have changed and forgot to update.